# Calculating Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this problem: List of customers with their next scheduled, reoccurring appointment, that is either yearly, monthly, or quarterly.

The tables\columns I have are:

```
customer
   customer_ID
service
   customer_ID
   service_RecID
Resource
   service_RecID
   Recurrence_RecID
   Date_Time_Start
Recurrence
   Recurrence_RecID
   RecurType
   RecurInterval
   DaysOfWeek
   AbsDayNbr
   SelectInterval
```

It is modeled such that when the schedule is setup, the date_start_time is the date of when the first reoccurring appointment took place. Ex.

```
Recurrence_RecID = 10
RecurType = m (could be y, or d as well for yearly or daily)
RecurInterval = 6 (if recurType = y, this would mean every 6 years)
```

Given that the system generates these nightly, how would I write a query to calculate the next scheduled appointment, for each customer? I originally thought of using the Resource.Date_Time_Start and just cycling through until a variable nextAppointment >= today(), but is it good practice to run loops in SQL?

If anymore info is needed, let me know. Thank you much!

Edit: I will make a sqlfiddle.

Comment: can you make a sqlfiddle ?

Comment: So 'd' in RecurType means 'quarterly'?

Comment: You could make your life a whole heap easier by recording the date of the last time the user was scheduled for an appointment, so you only have to deal with adding one interval of your recurrence.  You might need a second column in the Resource table so as to record the first and the latest appointments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a sub-query as opposed to looping. More efficient that way. This may not be exact but something like...

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
(      
SELECT
    customer.customer_id,
    service.service_RecID,
    Resource.Date_Time_Start,
    Recurrence.Recurrence_RecID,
    RecurType,
    RecurInterval,
    DaysOfWeek,
    AbsDayNbr,
    SelectInterval,
    NextAppointmentDate=
    CASE 
        WHEN RecurType='m' THEN DATEADD(MONTH,RecurInterval,Resource.Date_Time_Start)
        WHEN RecurType='y' THEN DATEADD(YEAR,RecurInterval,Resource.Date_Time_Start)
    ELSE 
        NULL
    END        
FROM
    Recurrence
    INNER JOIN Resource ON Resource.Recurrence_RecID=Recurrence.Recurrence_RecID
    INNER JOIN service ON service.service_RecID=Resource.service_RecID
    INNER JOIN customer ON customer.customer_ID=service.customerID
)AS X
WHERE
    NextAppointmentDate>=GETDATE()
ORDER BY Fields...
```